# How to change the value of a file object?

Tags: java

In the following code, I'm trying to create a way to verify if what a user entered is a file that exists, and then prompts them repeatedly until they enter something that does exist.

```
System.out.print("Input file name: ");
String entry = console.nextLine().toLowerCase();
File f = new File(entry + ".txt");
while(!f.exists()){
System.out.print("File not found. Try again: ");
     f.equals(console.next().toLowerCase() + ".txt");
}
```

Sorry if its a stupid question, I'm just new to java and don't know why this doesn't work. For example, if there's only one file named "testing.txt", and their first entry is "potato", I want it to prompt them until they enter the name of a file that does exist.

Comment: Change the last line of your loop to `f = new File(console.nextLine() + ".txt");`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Wow alright, I'm used to the new keyword not working when reassigning variables. Thanks, now I feel stupid XD

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter File Name: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file = new File(scanner.nextLine()+".txt");
    while(!file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found. Try Again...");
        file = new File(scanner.nextLine()+".txt");
    }
    System.out.println("File Found. "+file.getName());
    scanner.close();
}
```